# How to sort a nested array based on value with lodash?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, filter, lodash

I'm in the midst of learning how to use the lodash library, but I've bumped into a problem that I don' think I know how to solve. I want to sort a nested array that looks like this with lodash:

```
"results": [
  {
        "id": "12345",
        "name": "toy123",
        "date_created": "2017-08-29T16:10:37Z",
        "date_last_modified": "2019-01-29T17:19:36Z",
        "prices": [
            {
                "currency": "USD",
                "amount": "100.00"
            },
            {
                "currency": "EUR",
                "amount": "88.23"
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "54321",
        "name": "toy321",
        "date_created": "2017-08-29T16:10:37Z",
        "date_last_modified": "2019-01-29T17:19:36Z",
        "prices": [
            {
                "currency": "USD",
                "amount": "80.00"
            },
            {
                "currency": "EUR",
                "amount": "70.58"
            },
        ]
    },
]
```

I want to sort the array based on the `prices` array that is nested in the given array. The sorting will take consideration of the `prices.currency` and `prices.amount` and produce the output as below where the given array is sorted ascendingly based on `USD` and `amount`. And another problem I have is that the `prices.amount` is a string, not a number.

```
[
    {
        "id": "54321",
        "name": "toy321",
        "date_created": "2017-08-29T16:10:37Z",
        "date_last_modified": "2019-01-29T17:19:36Z",
        "prices": [
            {
                "currency": "USD",
                "amount": "80.00"
            },
            {
                "currency": "EUR",
                "amount": "70.58"
            },
        ]
  },
  {
        "id": "12345",
        "name": "toy123",
        "date_created": "2017-08-29T16:10:37Z",
        "date_last_modified": "2019-01-29T17:19:36Z",
        "prices": [
            {
                "currency": "USD",
                "amount": "100.00"
            },
            {
                "currency": "EUR",
                "amount": "88.23"
            },
        ]
    },
]
```

Many thanks in advance for your kindness and of course your time.

Comment: Can you elaborate the sorting part. What do you mean by sorting on USD and amount base?

Comment: price.amount is not an issue because you'd get the flexibility of first parseInt and then compare

Comment: @binariedMe it means the array is sorted based on the amount with the currency in USD.

Comment: Well, others have already answered as per your requirement then. I think they should work fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`_.sortBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/#sortBy) method does not support a custom comparator, you should use [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) instead. You don't need to parse `prices.amount` either, [`String.prototype.localeCompare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) can do the comparison for you, it supports strings with numeric values.

Putting it all together, your implementation might look something like this:

```
results.sort((a, b) => {
    const priceA = _.find(a.prices, { currency: 'USD' });
    const priceB = _.find(b.prices, { currency: 'USD' });
    return priceA.amount.localeCompare(priceB.amount, undefined, { numeric: true });
});
```

Comment: This is going to construct a new comparison function for every item in the array, look at my solution below to see how to cache the comparison function for better performance.

Comment: Sure you are looking at my solution?

Comment: Sorry, I saw "cache" and saw the other answer with "cache". I wasn't aware of `Intl.Collator` thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 4):

No need for external libraries like loadash.

```js
const arr = [
  {
        "id": "12345",
        "name": "toy123",
        "date_created": "2017-08-29T16:10:37Z",
        "date_last_modified": "2019-01-29T17:19:36Z",
        "prices": [
            {
                "currency": "USD",
                "amount": "100.00"
            },
            {
                "currency": "EUR",
                "amount": "88.23"
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "54321",
        "name": "toy321",
        "date_created": "2017-08-29T16:10:37Z",
        "date_last_modified": "2019-01-29T17:19:36Z",
        "prices": [
            {
                "currency": "USD",
                "amount": "80.00"
            },
            {
                "currency": "EUR",
                "amount": "70.58"
            },
        ]
    },
];

const naturalSort = new Intl.Collator(undefined, { numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base' }).compare;

arr.sort((a,b) => naturalSort(a.prices.find(p => p.currency === 'USD').amount, b.prices.find(p => p.currency === 'USD').amount));

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: any particular reason you used `sensitivity: 'base' `?

Comment: Not really for this example, it probably come from a copy and paste in this example. I always use it when I create an intl collator to be case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

and optimise by caching the price lookup which will otherwise be performed on each item multiple times..

```js
const results = [
  {
    "id": "12345",
    "name": "toy123",
    "date_created": "2017-08-29T16:10:37Z",
    "date_last_modified": "2019-01-29T17:19:36Z",
    "prices": [
      { "currency": "USD", "amount": "100.00" },
      { "currency": "EUR", "amount": "88.23" },
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "54321",
    "name": "toy321",
    "date_created": "2017-08-29T16:10:37Z",
    "date_last_modified": "2019-01-29T17:19:36Z",
    "prices": [
      { "currency": "USD", "amount": "80.00" },
      { "currency": "EUR", "amount": "70.58" },
    ]
  },
];

function sortResults(results, curr) {
  return results
    .map(result => ([result, result.prices.find(price => price.currency === curr).amount - 0]))
    .sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1])
    .map(res => res[0]);
}

console.log(sortResults(results, "USD").map(res => res.name));
```